# How to fit a model using curve()

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I am pretty new to R - and I can't find a good answer to this via googling, so I appreciate your help. I have data that, when plotted, shows a logarithmic curve. I modeled it as lm(y~log(x)):

```
logEstimate <- lm(d$MaxHt~log(d$StemDens))
coef(logEstimate)
       (Intercept) log(Pycnan$TS) 
         51.37911       12.63334
```

I'd like to fit a curve from this model onto a plot of my original variables (x, y). I tried several different ways using curve(), but I kept getting error messages:

```
plot(d$MaxHt~d$StemDens)

curve(logEstimate, from=0, to=45, n=101, add=TRUE)
```

> Error in logEstimate(x) : could not find function "logEstimate"

```
curve(51.37911+12.63334*log(d$StemDens), from=0, to=45, n=101, add=TRUE)
```

> Error in curve(51.37911 + 12.63334 * log(Pycnan$TS), add = TRUE, col =
>   2) : 
>       'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'

I'm not sure how to make logEstimate a function. I'm also not sure if I am missing a step to back transform my coefficients before I try to fit them to a plot of the original data. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample data that can be copy/pasted into R so that possible solutions can be tested and verified. But in most cases like this, you should use `predict()` rather than `curve()`

Comment: You need a function and not a data vector, just to use 'x' in place of d$StemDens.  Use `curve(51.37911+12.63334*log(x), from=0, to=45, n=101, add=TRUE)`